# Two variations of Hilbert's 90 theorem

Tags: field-theory, galois-theory, galois-cohomology

Let $L/K$ be a finite Galois extension.
I know that $H^1(Gal(L/K), L^{\times}) = 0$ and $H^r(Gal(L/K), (L,+)) = 0$ for all $r>0$.

1) Do we have $H^r(Gal(L/K), L^{\times}) = 0$ for all $r>1$ ?

2) Do we have $H^1(Gal(L/K), (L^{\times})^n) = 0$ for all $n>1$, where I'm using the diagonal action on the product ?

Thank you!

Comment: Another variation is when $L^{\times}$ is considered as trivial Galois module, see theorem 3.8 [here](https://www.uni-due.de/~hx0149/notes_files/AVQMF-article.pdf) for the proof that $H^2(Gal(\bar Q / Q), \bar Q^{\times}) = 0$ is that case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the following, write $G=Gal(L/K)$.

1) The main reason behind the nullity of all the cohomology groups $H^r(G, (L,+))$ is the *so-called normal basis theorem*: there exists $x\in L$ s.t. the system $s(x)$, for $s$ running through $G$, is a basis of the $K$-vector space $L$, in other words, $L$ is a $K[G]$-free module, hence has trivial cohomology.

2) The multiplicative version of Hilbert's thm.90 states that $H^1(G, L^*)=0$, but the higher cohomology groups do not vanish in general. And fortunately so, because what would be the interest of the cohomology theory of fields ? Here is a list of the most interesting cases:

a) If $K$ is a finite field, $G$ is cyclic, generated by the Frobenius automorphism. But in the cyclic case, say with $G=<\phi>$, it is known that $H^2(G, L^*)\cong K^*/NL^*$ and $H^1(G, L^*)\cong KerN/(L^*)^{\phi-1}$, where $N$ denotes the norm map. Since $L^*$ is finite, the kernel and cokernel of $\phi-1$ have the same order, and Hilbert's 90 then immediately implies the nullity of $H^2(G, L^*)$. This last property is known as the surjectivity of the norm in a finite extension of finite fields.

b) In the general case, $H^2(G, L^*)$ is known to be canonically isomorphic to the *relative* Brauer group $Br(L/K)$, which is a subgroup of the *absolute* Brauer group $Br(K)$, with exponent dividing the degree $[L:K]$. Recall that $Br(K)$ is a fundamental object which classifies the equivalence classes of central simple $K$-algebras.

c) Even "better", in local CFT, which describes the abelian extensions of a local $p$-adic field, $Br(L/K)$ is cyclic of order $[L:K]$, generated by a so-called *fundamental class* $u(L/K)$ which encapsulates the main properties of the theory. For instance, the cup-product with $u(L/K)$ defines an isomorphism of the abelian quotient $G^{ab}$ onto $K^*/NL^*$ (the inverse of this isomorphism is usually called the *local reciprocity map* or the *norm residue symbol*). More generally, the whole $G$-cohomology of $L^*$ is given by the cup-product with $u(L/K)$, which gives $H^r(G,\mathbf Z)\cong H^{r+2}(G,L^*)$ for all $r\in \mathbf Z$ (modified Tate cohomology groups here).

NB: On the archimedean side, as recalled by @Lord Shark the Unknown, local CFT boils down to an isomorphism $H^2(G(\mathbf C/\mathbf R), \mathbf C^*)\cong \mathbf Z/2\mathbf Z)$, and the fundamental class corresponds to the quaternion algebra.

d) In global CFT (for number fields or, more generally, global fields), one must replace $L^*$ gy the *idèle class group* $C_L$, and the main key is again a certain fundamental class $u(L/K)\in H^2(G, C_L)$ which has properties similar to those of the local classes. From these one can deduce global-local properties of the cohomology groups $H^r(G,L^*)$. For example, $H^3(G,L^*)$ is cyclic of order $n/n_0$, the global degree divided by the l.c.m. of the local degrees, generated by the *Teichmüller class* $\delta(u(L/K))$, where $\delta$ is the natural map $H^2(G, C_L) \to H^2(G, L^*)$.

For local and global CFT, I refer to chapters VI and VII of Cassels-Fröhlich.

3) You ask for $H^1(G,(L^*)^n$) with diagonal action of $G$ on the direct product. I wonder why, since this is not a very natural action. Anyway, if $A, B$ are two $G$-modules, then naturally $H^r(G, A\times B)\cong H^r(G,A)\times H^r(G,B)$  ./.

Comment: Thank you! Could you have a look to the related question https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2931496 ? :-)

Comment: Because of the limited space devoted to a comment, I posted an answer to your question  math.stackexchange.com/questions/2931496

Answer (score 0):

We don't in general have $H^2(\textrm{Gal}(L/K),L^\times)=0$. These $H^2$ groups are related to [Brauer groups](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brauer_group), which classify central division algebras over $K$.
In particular $H^2(\textrm{Gal}(L/K),L^\times)$ is the *relative Brauer group*
$\text{Br}(L/K)$, the kernel of the natural map $\text{Br}(K)\to
\text{Br}(L)$ between the Brauer groups
of $K$ and $L$.

An easy special case is $H^2(\textrm{Gal}(\Bbb C/\Bbb R),\Bbb C^\times)
\cong\Bbb Z/2\Bbb Z$.

Comment: Yes, I see. What about the $H^3$, for instance ?

Comment: Tate says something about $H^3$ in his article on global class field theory in "Cassels and Frohlich". It isn't always zero. @Alphonse